# How to remove a MSI product when the uninstaller says the package is missing?

Tags: vpn, windows-10, windows-installer, uninstall

Could someone please help me to resolve this issue of not being able to find an `.msi` file during uninstalling Palo Alto GlobalProtect VPN client on Windows 10?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

You can enumerate products on your machine with `msiinv.exe -P` to retrieve the product code and cached database path.

You can then remove the specific item with `msiexec.exe /x <productcode>` or `msiexec.exe /x <path to cached DB>`

Example output of msiinv.exe:

```
MySampleProduct
        Product code:   {5f8bec5d-0196-4e29-9195-292e75ef7619}
        Product state:  (5) Installed.
        Assignment:     per machine
        Package code:   {66ad8add-4b68-4609-9333-802d7668da82}
        Version:        5.1.1
        Publisher:      Example Corporation
        Language:       1033
        Installed from: C:\ProgramData\ExamplePackages\Package,version=1.1.1.0\
            Package:    Example.msi
        Product Icon:   C:\Windows\Installer\{5f8bec5d-0196-4e29-9195-292e75ef7619}\icon.ico
        Instance type:  0
        Local package:  C:\Windows\Installer\24cd76c.msi
        Install date:   2018\03\10
```

In this case, you could do:
`msiexec /x {5f8bec5d-0196-4e29-9195-292e75ef7619}`
or
`msiexec /x C:\Windows\Installer\24cd76c.msi`

Msiinv.exe is available from https://github.com/ZisBoom/MsiInv.exe/blob/master/exe/msiinv.exe
(I am original author of the tool.)

Answer (score -1):

Please reinstall it and remove it just after.

As stated by the installer, it's looking for the installer package, that is no longer inside your computer.

[image]

*The installer seem to have put the msi in a temp folder, the file must have been simply deleted over time.*